# QTableWidget: How can I get tighter lines with less vertical spacing padding?

Tags: qt, qt4, qtablewidget

The [QTableWdiget](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.5/qtablewidget.html) is fabulous for simple grid displays.  Changing colors, fonts, etc is straightforward.

However, I did not manage to give the grid a 'tighter' look with less vertical whitespace.  I see that the Qt documentation talks (eg [here](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.5/qtextframeformat.html)) about

- margin
- border
- padding

around widgets, but when I set these I only get changes *around the entire* grid widget rather than inside.

How can I set this (with a style sheet, or hard-coded options) directly to make the QTableWidget display tighter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code getting 'h' might be unsound.  It was just an example.  Copy & paste the following rather rudimentary code.  Change the value in "setDefaultSectionSize()", recompile, and run.  You should see the difference.  Setting this to 10 or 50 yields visible results.  In the code above, it is possible QFontMetrics or QFont is messing something up.

You can use whatever you want to get the height, but font size makes the most sense.

```
#include <QtGui>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
 QApplication app( argc, argv );

 QDialog* my_dialog  = new QDialog();
 QHBoxLayout* layout  = new QHBoxLayout();
 QTableWidget* my_table_widget = new QTableWidget( my_dialog );

 my_table_widget->setRowCount( 10 );
 my_table_widget->setColumnCount( 10 );
 my_table_widget->verticalHeader()->setDefaultSectionSize( 15 );
 layout->addWidget( my_table_widget );
 my_dialog->setLayout( layout );
 my_dialog->resize( 500, 200 );
 my_dialog->show();

 return app.exec();
}
```

EDIT: I don't know how to format a block of code here... forgive me. :)

*Edit 2*: I fixed that, and the following simple `tighterTable.pro` file
helps along.

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET =
DEPENDPATH += .
INCLUDEPATH += .

SOURCES += tighterTable.cpp    # if that is the filename
```

Thanks a big fat bunch for this.  BTW: Editing as code is just indenting by four spaces, and/or hitting the button with the little '101010' in the formatting row.

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for has a very silly solution IMHO, but it works. You need to set the headers' defaultSectionSize() members.  Accessed via verticalHeader() & horizontalHeader().  I never really set the column width's w/ this b/c most of my projects involve me adding rows, not columns, and I just call resizeColumnsToContents or do a manual resizing.  However, the rows is irksome.  I generally get the height of the font using QFontMetrics, and add 2. Any subsequent row added should have this height, and viola: tighter look.

Hope that helps.

**EDIT:**

Untested code:

```
QFontMetrics fm( my_font );
int h = fm.height() + 2;
my_table->verticalHeader()->setDefaultSectionSize( h );
```

Comment: Paul, I can't get to work. I get `fm` and `h` and can set, but the table does not change in appearance. It also does not matter whether I delete rows and add new ones -- they all have that extra little bit of vertical spacing.

Answer (score 3):

QTableWidget is a convenience model and view.  Typically, `QAbstractItemModel`'s data() method provides a [SizeHintRole](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum) that is used to tell the view what size each cell should be.

Since you're using QTableWidget, I don't think there's anything that you can do to change the size hint being returned by its internal model. Even the [Qt style sheet documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/stylesheet-reference.html#qtableview-widget) mentions nothing in that area.

Comment: Hi Kaleb, I appreciate the answer -- I had more or less arrived at a similar conclusion ("just can't do this")  but it is good to have a second pair of eyes on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

QTableWidget -> verticalHeader -> setMinimumSectionSize() is the right way, and it can be set in ui.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the answers here without success. What worked for me though was setting **both** the following.

```
    table->verticalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents)
    table->verticalHeader()->setMaximumSectionSize(10)
```